# How can I generate VGG16 multi features in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, model

I want to get multi features in VGG16, and i write code in `build()` like:

```
      # ...
      # ch=256
      self.front_feature = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        vgg16.get_layer("input_1"),
        # Original size
        vgg16.get_layer("block1_conv1"), vgg16.get_layer("block1_conv2"), vgg16.get_layer("block1_pool"),
        # Original size / 2
        vgg16.get_layer("block2_conv1"), vgg16.get_layer("block2_conv2"), vgg16.get_layer("block2_pool"),
        # Original size / 4
        vgg16.get_layer("block3_conv1"), vgg16.get_layer("block3_conv2"), vgg16.get_layer("block3_conv3"), 
        # Original size / 4
        vgg16.get_layer("block3_pool"),
        # Original size / 8
        ],
        name=self.feature_layer_name+'_front'
      )
      # ch=512
      self.l4_feature = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        # Original size / 8
        vgg16.get_layer("block4_conv1"), vgg16.get_layer("block4_conv2"), vgg16.get_layer("block4_conv3"),
        # Original size / 8
        ],
        name=self.feature_layer_name+'_L4'
      )
      self.l4_pool = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        # Original size / 8
        vgg16.get_layer("block4_pool"),
        # Original size / 16
        ],
        name=self.feature_layer_name+'_L4_pooling'
      )
      # ch=512
      self.l5_feature = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        # Original size / 16
        vgg16.get_layer("block5_conv1"), vgg16.get_layer("block5_conv2"), vgg16.get_layer("block5_conv3"),
        # Original size / 16
        ],
        name=self.feature_layer_name+'_L5'
      )
      self.l5_pool = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        # Original size / 16
        vgg16.get_layer("block5_pool"),
        # Original size / 32
        ],
        name=self.feature_layer_name+'_L5_pooling'
      )
```

but it some stupid so i try to writen then into just one model object like:

```
  vgg16=tf.keras.applications.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
  self.feature_model_t = tf.keras.Model(
        inputs=vgg16.input,
        outouts=[
          vgg16.get_layer('block3_pool').output,
          vgg16.get_layer('block4_conv3').output,
          vgg16.get_layer('block4_pool').output,
          vgg16.get_layer('block5_conv3').output
        ],
      )
```

then i run the code, but get

TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'inputs')

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that you have the latest version of TensorFlow installed.

If this happens with TensorFlow 2.1, please downgrade to TensorFlow 2.0. Also, if you have Keras installed, you could just uninstall it since you use Keras from inside TensorFlow.

EDIT: If the problem still persists, ensure that you pass the correct parameter to your arguments inputs(hint: check if you correctly retrieve the input of VGG16).

Also, you would also have a problem because of the typo in '`outouts`';please rename to `outputs`

Comment: I test both 2.0.0 and 2.1.0, same problem TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'inputs').

Comment: Are you passing to inputs the correct Input from VGG16?

Comment: Kindly also upvote for the answer if it solved your problem, thank you very much.